# Errors when using conda install PyMC3

Tags: python, anaconda, pymc3, conda-forge

I am attempting to install PyMC3 package via Anaconda with Python 3.7 64 bit on WIN10. I used the command

```
conda install -c conda-forge pymc3
```

And error messages come out at the end

```
C:\Users\alway>SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
C:\Users\alway>SET MSSdk=1
C:\Users\alway>SET platform=
C:\Users\alway>IF /I [AMD64] == [amd64] set "platform=true"
C:\Users\alway>IF /I [] == [amd64] set "platform=true"
C:\Users\alway>if defined platform (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )  ELSE (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )

C:\Users\alway>for /F "skip=2 tokens=2,*" %A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" /v InstallDir') do SET "VSINSTALLDIR=%B"
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

C:\Users\alway>if "" == "" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=" )

C:\Users\alway>if "" == "" (
ECHO "WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
 GOTO End
)
"WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
The system cannot find the batch label specified - End
```

Anyone knows what is going on? I tried to install C++ compiler by

```
conda install libpython m2w64-toolchain -c msys2
```

but it did not work.
Now the error messages come out every time I open the terminal from Anaconda.
When I opened a JupyterNotebook and import libraries below, everything works well.

```
import arviz as az
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pymc3 as pm
from theano import shared
```